# Why does Rails ignore content-type when accepts is different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a RESTful controller:

```
class Api::V1::DevicesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user

  respond_to :json  
  # PUT /api/v1/devices/1
  def update
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :update, @device

    @device.update_attributes(params[:device])
    respond_with @device
  end

end
```

And some JS on the client side:

```
$("#click-me").on('click', function() {
   $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: '/api/v1/devices/' + $(this).data('device-id'),
    dataType: 'json',
    accept: 'application/json',
    data: {device: {user_id: null}, format: 'json'},
    success: function () {
      alert("Booya!"); 
    }
  })
});
```

When the AJAX gets fired, by default, jQuery sends a JS object as a URL encoded string.
And a `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is fine. And because I set `dataType` to `'json'`, it sets `Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`, which also seems fine.

However when Rails gets the request, it treats the post body as JSON, even tho content-type is URL Encoded. Is this a bug?

My solution so far is to cast the JS object as JSON (`JSON.stringify({device: {user_id: null}, format: 'json'})`) and just submit it.

But that doesn't feel very good, surely Rails should handle Content-Type and Accept separately. This app is in 3.0.17. Perhaps it's an issue with earlier versions?

**UPDATE:**

Turns out the 422 I was receiving was a validation failure, and Rack is smart enough to deal with varying Content-Type and Accept headers. Duh.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe due to the

```
dataType: 'json',
```

line, which informs the server that the content of your request is JSON.

Comment: You could be right, but I'm still curious as to why the request headers are:
`Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`. As far as I know Accept is for the document type you want back, and Content-Type is for the incoming document type.

Comment: Which error does make you think Rails is trying to read JSON? Rack automatically converts the body into a hash, so maybe this is the confusion point.

Comment: And, my response is wrong. the dataType option is for returned data.

Comment: I guess my assumption that may be wrong is, that Rack should be trying to convert a `urlencoded` document given the Content-Type is that, however I get a 422 when the data is urlencoded, and it works when I cast it into a JSON string (despite not changing the headers)

Comment: I think I may have not been thorough enough, the 422 is coming from a validation failure..

Comment: Thanks for your time! It was indeed a convoluted validation failure. Rack is smart enough indeed... :)